# why the rocon_app_manager is not launched?

Tags: ros, multi-robot, rocon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am learnig [ROCON](https://github.com/robotics-in-concert) which is an exellent example of multi-robot system.  I am trying to run [multinav_concert](https://github.com/robotics-in-concert/rocon_tutorials/tree/hydro/concert_tutorials/multinav_concert) in ROCON's Hydro repository.  As the multinav.concert file says, firstly  a rviz interface without map is launched by running concert.launch file in a terminal, secondly, map is loaded into rviz by running multinav_database_client.launch in another terminal which communicates with the first terminal.

Here is my question, How the map is loaded into rviz?  As the multinav.rapps shows map_sever is wrapped into a rapp " map_sharing", The rapp "map_sharing" includes map_sharing.launch which launchs node /map and related topics.

However,  to my understandings, by tracing the process of running multinav_database_client.launch, concert_client.launch, paired_private.launch, then _app_manger_gateway.xml, _app_manger.xml are launched one by one, so the rapp "map_sharing" is managed by _app_manger.xml  which utilizes rocon_app_manager package.  The rocon_app_manger contains rapp_manager.py and other .py files

To understand this process, I added print function in _**init**, _process_start_app, _process_stop_app in rapp_mangaer.py to show some infomation about the process, but nothing is output on the screen. It seems that rocon_app_manager doesn't do anything for the process of loading map sucessfully.

I once modified the rapp "nav_demo" to be "nav_test" by trying to launch amcl node( adding amcl_demo.launch) but failed to launch amcl node(please see [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/156116/why-the-amcl-cant-be-launched-in-a-robot-app/) on ros answer)

So I wonder why the rapp runnig map server is loaded sucessfully but another rapp with amcl can't be launched.

I am very confused and don't know how to solve this. Any guidance will be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/156551/why-the-rocon_app_manager-is-not-launched-?/) by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 279 on 2014-04-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2014-04-22**:
Ok, I found that If I add --screen when launch multinav_database_client.launch，all information from rospy.logwarn, rospy.loginfo including the manually added print function are shown in the screen. How this comes?  How to make these information from rospy.logxxx in the code hidden or open without inputing ‘--screen’ in the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All the output from rapp are generated by rapp_manager.py node.  If you add output="screen" in app_manager node should output the log of rapps without --screen.

This file starts the app manager node. https://github.com/robotics-in-concert/rocon_app_platform/blob/hydro/rocon_app_manager/launch/includes/_app_manager.xml

---

Originally posted by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) with karma: 634 on 2014-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0